# Generate Html with javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I want to generate an img tag like this with javascript:

```
<img id="drag0" src="http://localhost:34737/Images/MainSlider/A(1).jpg" class="col-4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

and drag method:

```
document.addEventListener("drag", function (ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}, false);
```

When I generate the dynamic html it's not working as expected and it returns this in the DOM:

```
 <img id="drag1" src="http://localhost:34737/Images/MainSlider/B(1).jpg" class="col-4" draggable="true" ondragstart="function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData(&quot;text&quot;, ev.target.id);}">
```

This is my javascript code:

```
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 img.setAttribute("id", "drag" + i);
 img.setAttribute("src", user[i].MainPicAddress);
 img.setAttribute("class", "col-" + e);
 img.setAttribute("draggable", true);
 img.setAttribute("ondragstart", drag);
```

Comment: img.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");  ?

Comment: Don't attach events by `on*` attributes, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your `ondragstart` attribute value in quotes like this :

```
img.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding double quotes around the setAttribute 2nd parameter.

```
img.setAttribute("ondragstart", 'drag(event)');
```

or something like

```
img.setAttribute("ondragstart", 'drag');
```